# How to change column name for child class (InheritanceType.Joined)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to change name of column in child class when using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`

So my base class looks like this:

```
@Table(name = "expense_general_entry")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseClass {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
}
```

Child class

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "childClassId")
public class Child extends BaseClass{
   //Some data
}
```

I would like to have field `childClassId` in `Child` class, instead of id, but with value of id. Right no now Child class has this field, but it's always null, instead there is `id` field with set value. When I add this column like this

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "childClassId")
public class Child extends BaseClass{
   @Column(name="childClassId")
   private Long childClassId;
}
```

I receive exceptions that "childClassId" can not be null.

---

Table Structures

```
Base class
Id (PK) | version | name
```

```
Child class
ChildId (PK) AND (FK -> Base.Id) | childSpecificField
```

When I insert new row, `Child` has atribute `ID` set, but not the `ChildId` (which is always null) - and i need to set both, id and childId.

Comment: This `@Columna(name-"childClassId")` should by `@Column(name="childClassId")` ?

Comment: Yep, just a typo on stack

Comment: Could you please also show your db tables structure related to this mapping.

Comment: Yep, no problem, done. Basically `childClassId` field is Primary Key for ChildClass and foreign key to BaseClass, because of `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "childClassId")`